# How to turn off metaball lines in blender?

Tags: rendering, meta-objects

I am going to do a viewport render (as I can't render in eevee as the material/gloss goes flat in the metaballs) - you can see in the image. I just want to remove these metaball black lines around them so It doesn't show up in my render.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I don't think you can hide them. Why not just render in Eevee? What do you mean by "material goes flat"? :)

Comment: the reflections you see on the ball up above is what I would want but I cant see them when I render in eevee. theres only solid pink colour :)

Comment: The reflections come from an HDRI (environment) texture :). You can easily add it to your renders as well.

Comment: They cannot be removed as they are for manipulation or selection.